Deploy Dockerized image from Amazon ECR to an EC2 instance using Amazon ECS
I cannot run a task on ECS cluster, because the EC2 instance is not backedup up to cluster.
I have pushed my containerised image to amazon ECR. I have created EC2 instance with auto-scaling group and user data as #!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=cluster-name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
where cluster-name is my ECS cluster name.
After i create a cluster i dont have my container instances running on my cluster. When i create a task in the cluster using launch type as EC2, it gives me this error message. Am i wrong somewhere? or have to follow any additional steps to run a task on cluster?

You need to look at the ECS agent logs on the EC2 instance to see why it is unable to join the ECS cluster. Are you even using an EC2 AMI that has the ECS agent installed on it? If you aren't using an ECS optimized AMI, you will have to install the ECS agent https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html

Also, I'm not sure why this is tagged with aws-lambda. There is nothing about AWS Lambda in your question.
